# Get rid of "'NSObject' may not respond to '-someMethod'" warning

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm learning ObjectiveC and ran into a problem relating to introspection. Basically, I'm looping through an array of objects and determining if they accept the `lowercaseString` selector. If they do, I call that selector on the object. After I ensure that the object responds to that selector, I call it. However, when I do, I get this warning: "warning: 'NSObject; may not respond to '-lowercaseString'"

Although the code works fine as written, I'd like to not get the warning. I'm assuming that there's a "right" way to make sure that I don't get that warning (i.e. without just turning warnings off). Any ideas?

```
NSMutableArray *myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

[myArray addObject:@"Hello!"];
[myArray addObject:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://apple.com"]];
[myArray addObject:[NSProcessInfo processInfo]];
[myArray addObject:[NSDictionary dictionary]];

SEL lowercaseSelector = @selector(lowercaseString);

for (NSObject *element in myArray) {
    if ([element respondsToSelector:lowercaseSelector]) {
        NSLog([element lowercaseString]); // Warning here
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, if I'm getting the "selector" terminology wrong, please correct me. :)

Comment: *Don't* pass non-constant strings to NSLog. There's a security risk. You may think you're safe in this case, but don't get in the habit of it. You'll inevitably end up doing it in a case that does open a security hole.

Comment: Do you have a link to more information about this security hole? I'm definitely interested in reading more about it.

Comment: You should always pass a format string for the first arg of NSLog. If any of the elements in your array contain formatting characters, NSLog will try to read the associated arguments, but you won't have passed any. Instead write NSLog(@"%@", [element lowercaseString]);.

Comment: It's not just a security hole, it's a potential crash.  If the string contains %s or %@ it's going to indiscriminantly treat the random bytes on the stack as a pointer, deference them and if you used %@, send the [self description] message to it.  As Jim says, and for *any* function that takes a format string (like stringWithFormat:), ensure that you pass a *format*.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can also use `id` which is any type of object.

```
for (id element in myArray) {
    if ([element respondsToSelector:lowercaseSelector]) {
        NSLog([element lowercaseString]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I figured NSObject would be the proper one, but, indeed, id seems a better way of doing it.

Comment: as long as you don't need to call retain or release on element ;-)

Comment: If you have an object that conforms to a protocol and you use id<myProtocol> as the data type for it, it complains that retain/release (and other NSObject functions) aren't found in the protocol. It just assumes the protocol will define every method called on the object. Works fine otherwise - that particular situation drives me crazy, though!

Comment: The workaround to this is to make all your protocols conform to <NSObject (which is a protocol as well as a class). Anyway, this doesn’t apply to plain id.

Comment: Very nice... I was trying to figure out how to suppress the warning with a compiler directive, but this is much better.

Answer (score 6):

How about using `performSelector:`?

```
SEL lowercaseSelector = @selector(lowercaseString);

for (NSObject *element in myArray) {
    if ([element respondsToSelector:lowercaseSelector]) {
        NSLog([element performSelector:lowercaseSelector]); // No warning
    }
}
```

This would get rid of your compiler warning.

Comment: Ah, this seems like a nice way to do it. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 4):

Just cast your NSObject to an NSString before calling the function:

```
for (NSObject *element in myArray) {
    if ([element respondsToSelector:lowercaseSelector]) {
        NSLog([(NSString*)element lowercaseString]); // No warning!
    }
}
```

Comment: But what if the object doesn't support all the selectors that NSString supports? My OOP-sense tells me that that would be bad. I'm just checking for one selector, regardless of what superclass it belongs to.

Comment: Well, you're assuming that -lowercaseString returns an NSString, since that's what NSLog expects for the format string. If, for whatever reason, it doesn't return an NSString, then you're passing something other than an NSString as the format string, and NSLog will choke on it.

Comment: The safest way would be to get the `lowercaseString`, store it in a variable, and test whether it's a kind of NSString. You probably don't need to be that paranoid, though, and if you're not going to be, you might as well declare the variable as, or cast the return value to, `NSString *`.

Answer (score 1):

Casting as id removed the warning.

```
if ([self.content respondsToSelector:@selector(setDelegate:)])
{
    [(id)self.content setDelegate:nil];
}
```